# Preserve form inputs between routes?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have begun using iron-router. I have a several page "wizard" form. At the end of each page there is a "Next" button with an href populated with a {{pathFor 'nextPage'}} href. This works fine... but, when I hit the back button, my user-inputted field values are gone.

I'm thinking of preserving the inputted values with jquery's data() calls or using Meteor's session, but I've got to believe there's a better (built-in?) way to do this. I just don't see any tips/documentation on it out there. I searched atmosphere for a package and found nothing that exactly matches it (a lot of form helpers like autoform, but not something specifically dovetailing with iron-router).

Any suggestions hugely appreciated.

Comment: What about using a session to store an object presenting the form inputs for each page?

Comment: That's what I was planning on. But I'll be writing code to preserve the state of any sort of form input and restore it in a post-render callback. That means refill inputs, textareas, radios, checkboxes, the whole gamut. I was kind of hoping somebody had created a package to do this already (that got along with iron-router). Seems like maybe writing that package will be up to me. When I'm done I'll repost here to leave breadcrumbs for the next person that needs something like that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to preserve data across multiple pages, I would create a collection that stores all of the relevant data for the wizard. So as the user works their way through the wizard, you're populating different parts of that collection document. Alternatively, as others have mentioned, you can store the data in Session. If the user refreshes the page, that data will be lost, but it could be accessible across your route changes.

It may be worth noting that in the dev branch of iron-router, named yields work a little differently. In the release version, the named yields of the layout are replaced on every new route. In other words, even if the template rendered is the same, it's still completely torn off the page and rendered again. In the dev branch the named yield region is only re-rendered if the template actually changes.

So in your case (in the dev branch) you might do something like the following (just to illustrate the concepts):

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('stepOne', {
    template: 'wizard', 
    path: '/stepOne',
    action: function () {
      Session.set('wizardStep', 'stepOne');
      this.render('wizard'); // same as this.render()
    }
  });

  this.route('stepTwo', {
    template: 'wizard',
    path: '/stepTwo',
    action: function () {
      Session.set('wizardStep', 'stepTwo');
      this.render();
    }
  });
});

<template name="wizard">
  {{#ifStepEquals "stepOne"}}
    <!-- do something with step one -->
  {{/ifStepEquals}}

  {{#ifStepEquals "stepTwo"}}
    <!-- do something here with step two -->
  {{/ifStepEquals}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited into an answer, just like on Jeopardy:

Craft your series of forms as a series of divs you hide or show, that are all in existence until the end, and there is nothing to move or preserve.

Answer 2:  Make your wizards edit on the insert the same way they would edit on an update.  Create an initial document, with a flag indicating is is unfinished, update its values from the DOM as you would during an edit, then update the flag once it has cleared all your wizard screens.  The templates become much more re-usable.

Comment: This isn't an answer, this would've been better suited as a comment to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb I've seen is: If you want to preserve values between page loads (which is what the back button does, reload the previous page) put them in the URL.

I don't think Meteor supports the sort of server side session you get in some web scripting languages, which seems to be what you're thinking of.

Comment: Meteor supports Sessions pretty nicely, both server and client-side, cf their docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#session.  Putting values in the url is so 1999 :-)